# throw event when element si sorted having created this element with appendTo

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, events, appendto

I have created a sortable component with jQueryUI and this works fine including when these elements has created by appendTo jQuery function.

```
$template.appendTo("#lista_criterios");

$( "#lista_criterios" ).sortable({
    handle: ".criterio-header",
    placeholder: "alert alert-info",
    axis: 'y',
    update: showMessage('alert-success', 'Ordenacion de criterios completada.')
});
```

when a need twow an event when the sort is finished update and others functionalities of sortable element don't works.

Please can you help me?

Note: the example code is not identical of original.

Comment: I try $( "#lista_criterios" ).sortable("refresh"). but not wotk. . .

Comment: What does `showMessage()` do? Does it return a function?

Comment: showMessage == alert(); thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, the only problem I see in it is that the `update` option expects an event handler, not whatever `showMessage()` is returning if anything. Thus you either need to **(1)** wrap it in a `function(){}` call, or else **(2)** set its return value to one. As you say it's equivalent to `alert`, so the former is likely easier:

```
$( "#lista_criterios" ).sortable({
    // ...
    update: function(e, ui) {
        showMessage('alert-success', 'Ordenacion de criterios completada.');
    }
});
```

or the second way:

```
function showMessage(arguments) {
     return function(event, ui) {
          // show my alert with the arguments above
     };
}
```

[Ref. documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update)

Comment: @Blacknet `update` points to a value. Before, you were executing `showMessage()` and assigning its return value to `update`. With the above, you assign to it a new function (functions are valid values, in fact it's what `update` expects), which executes `showMessage()`

Comment: Thank you so much. Now i undestand perfectly. I have read the documentation but not explain hot you must use these events. Only when they execute.